# How can I change Max Pool Size for particular database in MSSQL elastic pool in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

How can I change Max Pool Size for a particular database in MSSQL elastic pool in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change from Azure Portal > SQL-server > settings > configure

> See, [Change elastic pool storage
> size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-scale#change-elastic-pool-storage-size)

[image]

for database...

[image]

However, if you are looking for increasing beyond the Max size available, checkout: Resource limits for elastic pools using the [vCore purchasing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-scale#change-elastic-pool-storage-size) and [DTU purchasing model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-dtu-elastic-pools)

And....

The following MS doc, [Request quota increases for Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/quota-increase-request#sqldbquota),  describe the quota increase options for the SQL Database quota types:

- Database transaction units (DTUs) per server
- Servers per subscription
- Region access for subscriptions or specific hardware